# Ruby On Rails circular association definition

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-associations

I'm building a Ruby on Rails application where I have a Locomotive and a Trip model.

Each locomotive can have many trips, and each trip belongs to one locomotive. The Trip model has a "begin" and "end" attribute, which are timestamps and can be null. Trip "end" is set once a locomotive on arrival of its destination; until then its' value is null.

Troubles start whenever I want to set the "end" attribute on the *last trip* for a particular locomotive ( id=45, for example). To this I must search within the set of all trips for a match on "locomotive_id=45" and search for those with a null "end" attribute. Only then I may be able to set the ending time.

In order to improve performance, I'm thinking of adding circular association with both models. Add a column to my Locomotive table named "last_trip_id", which can be null, that points to the Trip table and lets me know which row on that table is the last trip this locomotive has done.

I think this idea is awesome! :D However, I haven't found any documentation or tips regarding circular association on the ruby association guides or in it's API... So I don't know if this sort of implementation is encouraged on the RoR framework or not.

Would somebody give me some tips about this issue? Is it encouraged to add this circular association in order to have a better performance within this context?

Right now, my Locomotive and Trip models looks like this:

app/models/locomotive.rb

```
has_many :trips, dependent: :restrict_with_error
```

app/models/trip.rb

```
validates :locomotive_id, presence: true
belongs_to :locomotive
```

I think my new models should look like this:

app/models/locomotive.rb

```
has_many :trips, dependent: :restrict_with_error
belongs_to trip
```

app/models/trip.rb

```
validates :locomotive_id, presence: true
belongs_to :locomotive
has_one :locomotive
```

Which methods will add rails to my new models? Would I have some troubles when I write, for example:

```
> L=Locomotive.first
> L.trips.locomotives.trips.....
```

Best regards,

Karl

**EDIT 1**
Here you have my locomotives and trips structure:

db/schema.rb

```
...

create_table "locomotives", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "code"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end

...

create_table "trips", force: true do |t|
  t.integer  "locomotive_id"
  t.datetime "begin"
  t.datetime "end"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.string   "city_origin"
  t.string   "city_destination"
end
```

Comment: Why do you think you need to change your models as you describe? What they are now looks correct, but your proposed changes look invalid.

Comment: Because the models I have right now are valid for an association "one locomotive has many trips" and "one trip belongs to a single locomotive", but the enhancement I want to apply, is to add a *circular association* between Locomotive and Trip. That's why **I think** I may need to -besides generating a migration to add a new "last_trip_id" to my locomotives table- change my model as I proposed. Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need a circular association? Is it a many-to-many (e.g., perhaps a case for `has_and_belongs_to_many`)?

Comment: I think it is not a many to many, because one locomotive has many trips, and a trip will always belong to a single locomotive: it is a "one to many" association (there is no way a trip can be done by more than one locomotive!). I think that adding an extra table for a "has_and_belongs_to_many association" may solve my issue, but it would also complexify unnecesarily the problem, and I would rather like to perform the search on the Trip table. I would edit my main post to show you my tables structures.

Comment: Not answer relevant, but I'd use arrival/departure rather than begin/end for your trip model.

Comment: I'm not very familiar to english language... that's why I choose "begin" and "end". Arrival and departure are much better names! (since begin and end could collide with some rails instruction!!)

Answer (score 2):

I would structure the schema like so: remember that with your schema you are trying to model real world concepts as clearly as possible, so always start with real world intuitive concepts.

```
Station #list of stations

Locomotive #list of trains

#these are the **scheduled** journeys
Route
  start_station_id
  end_station_id
  departure_time
  arrival_time

#these are the **actual** journeys
Journey
  route_id
  locomotive_id
  actual_departure_time
  actual_arrival_time
```

So, Stations, Locomotives and Routes all exist in advance, and then a Journey record is created for every actual real life journey by a train.  The journey route_id and locomotive_id are filled when the journey is **scheduled**, and actual_departure_time and actual_arrival_time are filled in when the train actually leaves and arrives.

I think the names of the classes could be a bit better, and Journey could be decomposed further so that you have a table of start & end stations, and another with instances of these at different times, but you get the idea hopefully.

Comment: Ok, I think your approach it's similar to  wurde's: As far as I understand, you are advicing me to refactor my model's name in order to better modeling the real world situation, and to add a new table to associate locomotives with routes (or trips). Your approach also represents a good solution, but I would like some feedback comparing this approach with the "circular association approach", so I can decide which implementation would fit better my project. Thanks!

Comment: Circular associations are bad, as they can get out of sync.  But that's not the main problem - i just don't like your schema.

Comment: Also, worry about performance problems when you have them.  I would always recommend starting out with something that is as clear and simple as possible, and then later on you can refactor for performance if you need to.

Comment: Last year my teacher also told us that circular associations are **not recommended**, and ussualy are bad. However, she also told us that *in some cases*, circular associations could be helpful. That's why I want to know if this is one of those few cases where circular association could be a good solution, since my particular problem is very narrow, according to the specs.

Comment: Sorry Max, but for this question, I can't accept a sentence like "Circular associations are bad" as a final response.

Comment: OK: the danger of circular associations is that you could have a situation where A is linked to B with one of the associations, and linked to C with the other.  Given A, do we decide that A is linked with B or with C?  We could say that one of the associations is the "proper" one and takes precedence, but you're setting yourself up for problems when this isn't managed correctly.

Comment: For example, using my schema: let's say that as an optimisation we put `start_station_id` and `end_station_id` in Journey as well.  A Journey is created according to a Route which goes between London Victoria and Paris Gare De Nord.  Then, later, the Route is changed to go from London Euston to Paris Gare De Nord.  You're looking at the journey:  it says it starts at London Victoria and the associated Route says it starts at London Euston.  Which one do you believe?

Answer (score 1):

You could introduce a Schedule model that would hold these trips. This would allow you to sort by date range for locomotives arriving/departing.

Just take care if your modeling trips that may run 'late' or 'off' schedule.

```
class CreateTrainManagementSystem < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :locomotives do |t|
      t.float :speed
    end

    create_table :schedules do |t|
      t.integer :locomotive_id
      t.integer :route_id
      t.datetime :departure
      t.datetime :arrival
    end

    create_table :routes do |t|
      t.integer :origin
      t.integer :destination
      t.float :distance
    end

    create_table :trips do |t|
      t.integer :schedule_id
      t.datetime :departure
      t.datetime :arrival
    end

    create_table :stations do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.string :address
      t.string :city
      t.string :state
      t.integer :zip
      t.decimal :coord_x
      t.decimal :coord_y
    end
  end
end
```

To own this solution you can't just copy and paste it. This still needs models, validations and the like. It also solves more than just the performance issue. Think about calculating ETAs for delayed trains using speed, trip log, and route distances.

@Karl Hi, just saw in your comments that imply you're either a student or recent graduate. This is great news, you have a great resource here to ask questions. If you decide this is your craft and want to create solutions like mine, read Joe Celko's book Thinking In Sets.

Comment: Let me see if I understand: I could introduce "one to one" association Schedule model associated with trips. Each row on the Schedule model will hold the latest trip of a single locomotive. So each time one locomotive starts a new trip, I'd update his schedule row, so that it points to the new trip... I think I finally understood your comments!! The schedule model would be the "join table" between trips and locomotives! This is a simple solution, I like it! But I would be glad to have some feedback that compares this approach with the circular association approach . Thank you!

Comment: I will have more time to flesh this out with an example schema later. Glad to help.

Comment: I'm trying out a Delay model, will post results.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is to have an extra field from locomotive to the latest trip, so performance is better. If you set the right index on the trips table, maybe you don't need it.

Nevertheless, if you want to do it, here is how. Rails has the standard to set the name of the association to be identical to the classname. But this is no law. If your model get a little more complex, this is often no longer the right thing. So you can override it.

You call the association "latest trip" (or current_trip ?) and tell rails that it is actually a Trip-object.

locomotive.rb

```
belongs_to :latest_trip, 
  class_name: "Trip",
  foreign_key: "latest_trip_id"
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference

And you need to add a field "latest_trip_id" to the locomotives database table. You only need to be careful when you create and the objects, that all fields are correctly set.

You can have even several associations to Trip, like "funniest_trip", "accident_trips",....